# How to schedule a powershell script to be executed right after booting on Windows?

Tags: java, powershell, taskscheduler, windows-server-2016

I want to run a script starting some application on Windows when the machine is started/restarted.

I tried the [Register-ScheduledJob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psscheduledjob/register-scheduledjob?view=powershell-5.1) cmdlet :

```
Register-ScheduledJob -Name "MyJob" -ScriptBlock {.\C:\Users\Administrator\my_script.ps1 -input_value xyz} -Trigger (New-JobTrigger -AtStartup)
```

However, nothing gets executed at the startup and the output folder on

```
$home\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\ScheduledJobs directory
```

The Task Scheduler tool does not show anything as well.

my_script.ps1 simply starts a Java jar as follows:

```
param(
[parameter(Mandatory=$TRUE,Position=0)]
  [string] $input_value
)


write-output "Starting my Java app ... "

start powershell {java -jar slave.jar <<-some params ...>> ; Read-Host}
Exit 0
```

Even if I try to run the job with Start-Job -DefinitionName MyJob , nothing happens although it outputs that its running ...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know is if you run it in task [scheduler](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748993(v=ws.11).aspx).

```
schtasks /Create [/S <system> [/U <username> [/P [<password>]]]]
    [/RU <username> [/RP <password>]] /SC <schedule> [/MO <modifier>] [/D <day>]
    [/M <months>] [/I <idletime>] /TN <taskname> /TR <taskrun> [/ST <starttime>]
    [/RI <interval>] [ {/ET <endtime> | /DU <duration>} [/K] [/XML <xmlfile>] [/V1]]
    [/SD <startdate>] [/ED <enddate>] [/IT] [/Z] [/F]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a `Task` in `Task Scheduler` and set the `Trigger` as ***"When a specific event is logged"***

Then, set `Log:` to ***System*** and `Source:` to ***Kernal-General*** and `Event ID:` to ***12*** (or any event you would like to trigger the script on). ***12*** seems to always fire after a boot.

Under Action select ***Start a Program*** and set ***Program/script*** to `PowerShell`. In ***Add arguments (optional):*** enter  `-file "C:\YourDirectory\YourScript.ps1"`.